# How to have .htaccess url redirect and manage multiple calls to missing.html page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have set up my .htaccess to redirect calls to mydomain.com/something.html to mydomain.com/index.php?q=something

This works fine.... but I noticed that since moving to a new hosting I am getting multiple queries for the query "missing".
I am pretty sure it is due to the default html page for wrong URLs being "missing.html" which is redirected as mydomain.com/index.php?q=missing. So any missing URL will cause my PHP script to be run with "missing" as input.

Is there a way to keep the URL redirect and manage the calls to missing.html without actually calling my PHP script for missing URLs?

---

Edit with solution; here is my .htaccess which does the redirect only if there is no existing URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)\.html index.php?q=$1
```

Seems the RewriteCond need to be placed before (as shown above).

Comment: `RewriteCond` usually comes after `RewriteEngine on`; looks kinda weird with it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `RewriteCond`.

Try this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These rules will also stop rewriting for anything is an accessible path. If you want strictly `missing.html`, then the following rule will be sufficient:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/missing.html
```

Note these directives must come before `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Why do they need to "come before `RewriteRule`"?

Comment: Because it specifies the conditions that the following ``RewriteRule``s operate with, I believe (I may be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't is possible to add a rewriting rule which takes precedence over the other one and specifically rewrites mydomain.com/missing.html to the location of your 404 page? (Seing the redirection rule you already set up would help.)